# jquery clone and select/select2 selected values on jquery cloned elements getting lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently in trouble with a select/select2 and jQuery `$.clone` issue.

In a html form with html select boxes replaced with select2 but the select2 jQuery plugin is not really relevant for this issue.

I experience problems when I use jQuery `$.clone(true, true)` to get a copy of a form to work on it.

When I try the following:

```
window.clone =  $('#formSelector').clone(true,true);
```

The selected values are cloned and get lost. See http://jsfiddle.net/straeger/ct31f34c/9/

Even If I try to remove select2 with the call the cloned select boxes do not hold the selected values.

```
$('select').select2('destroy'); 
window.clone =  $('#formSelector').clone(true,true);
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/straeger/dokenyss/1/

A small hack with a big drawback (if no ID is present) is to copy the selected values to the clone:

```
$clone.find('select')
    .each(function(index, value){
        var $el = $(value);
        $el.val($element.find('#'+$el.attr('id')).val());
    });
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/straeger/ct31f34c/10/

My question is what would be the correct way to handle such a problem ?

Does anyone know a way to select the counterpart of the original element from the original jQuery element if I have no ID?

Or a way to persist the currently selected option ? via the attribute e.g.

```
<option value="c" selected>C Value</selected>
```